# Roadblocks in internal movement

Tags: manager, promotion, internal-transfer, depression

One of the manager from a different team approached my manager to find out if there is a good resource in my team for an open position. Manager said, I have been suggested as I deserve the most.

I was invited for lunch by that manager, had some discussions about the role and later given verbal offer, which I accepted happily.
It all looked promising until my senior manager came into the picture.

Ever since my manager had discussed this with my senior manager,
my manager has started saying things like *"you are too valuable for my team"*, *"I am worried about the current project"* and *"team would be weakened as another employee has decided to move out end of next month"*.

I have good connections with members of other team also and they whispered about my senior manager being a roadblock. Amid all these events, I am losing my concentration in current project, getting demoralized and afraid that other team might just forget about me.

How should I tackle this and grab that offer ?

Comment: Have you had any further contact with the manager for the new position?  If not I would reach out to them to see the status of your move to the new position,  Just because you hear gossip doesn't mean it is based in reality.

Comment: No I haven't reached out to the manager yet but think team lead is a good enough source. I am working on a high value project for them, so they do have a reason

Comment: Does the offering manager also report to your senior manager? If so, your senior manager can administratively block the transfer. If not, your senior manager is way out of line to even suggest holding on to you. - He is sacrificing your career growth for the sake of his project, and you should seriously consider what this means to you in the long term.

Comment: No offering manager doesn't report to my senior manager but still he is in line being my org's senior manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you consider talking to two managers and find an amicable solution till the project at your current position completes, you will spend certain percentage of your time dedicated to the success of that project ? To the new manager, you can say something like, you will make up for the lost time in the few months as taking up reading and follow ups, in your after work hours. It is not ideal, but if you want this new position bad enough, it might be the way to go

Comment: I tried saying this to my manager but it won't value until this is agreed upon between all the parties. I wasn't sure how to approach the other manager and thought giving some time too would be good idea so haven't approached. Will try think over a day more and then approach with this offer

Comment: But thanks for answering, I was having second thoughts about approaching the other manager. +1